# Play Station 2 games on android

Tags: emulators

Is it possible to play PS2 games on android and for free of course? Does it exist some PS2 emulator on android?

Comment: Did you look in the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

There are no PS2 emulators for Android yet, but there's a rumor on PCSX2 possibly being ported to Android sometime in the future. As of now, most devices don't have the desired computing power for PS2 emulation, but in the future they most likely will.

Comment: It would be of help to cite the source of this for the benefit of the OP.